# R Loop through two vectors and store results in dataframe

Tags: r, loops, rbind

I'd like to loop through elements in two vectors. After each iteration, I'd like to store the results of each iteration as a column in a dataframe. I'd like to continue the iteration till all elements of both vectors are covered.

**My Attempt**

```
# Define the size of my sample
n <- 446

# Preparing my vectors (n1 & n2)
p1 <- runif(18,0.8,0.95)
p2 <- 1 - p1
n1 <- round(p1*n)
n2 <- n - n1

#Creating empty df to store values of each iteration
df=data.frame()

#Building loop
for(i in 1:length(n1)) {
  for(j in 1:length(n2)) {
    tmp=sample(c(sample(4:5, n1[i], replace = TRUE), sample(1:3, n2[j], replace = TRUE)))
    df=rbind(df,tmp)
  }
}
```

However my loop doesn't seem to be creating the output I desire.

**Desired Output**

Ideally, the output would be -

1) A dataframe with 446 rows and 18 columns
2) With each column containing values between 1 to 5, as defined in previous steps

Any inputs would be highly appreciated

Comment: Can you create a _minimal_ example that we can replicate? Don't forget to use `set.seed` if you work with random numbers.

Comment: As per your example, I understand that the output will have length 446. But if you do the loop through the elements in two vectors, you will get, in this case, 18*18=324 outputs, not only 18. Can you explain better what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
set.seed(42)

# Define the size of my sample
n <- 446

# Preparing my vectors (n1 & n2)
p1 <- runif(18,0.8,0.95)
# p2 <- 1 - p1
n1 <- round(p1*n)
# n2 <- n - n1

D <- sapply(n1, function(n1i) sample(c(sample(4:5, n1i, replace = TRUE), sample(1:3, n-n1i, replace = TRUE))))
```

This will give you a matrix `D`. You can coerce it to a dataframe:

```
D2 <- as.data.frame(D)
```